# Calculating the value of y = 1/1 + 2/3 + 3/5 + 4/7 + ....... + n/(2n-1) where n is user input

Tags: java, addition, series

The problem with my code is that when I input 0, the result is 0.0 but whenever I enter anything more than zero, (like 1,2,3,4,5,6, 998...anything) the result is always 1.0 in each case. Is my logic incorrect inside the iteration?

My code:

```
    /*/  Write a y program that will calculate the value of y if the expression 
of y is as follows (n is the input):

        y = 1/1 + 2/3 + 3/5 + 4/7 + ....... + n/(2n-1)     /*/

import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

class Practice_Problems04_JavaPrograms_Task04{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner orcho = new Scanner(in);
        out.println("Please enter the value of n: ");
        int n = orcho.nextInt();
        double y = 0;

        for(int count = 1; count <= n; count++){
            y += (count / ((2 * count) - 1));
        }
        out.println("The summation is, y = " + y);
        orcho.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`count / ((2 * count) - 1)` is integer division, you need float number division, change to `count / ((2 * count) - 1.)`

When two integers made a division operation, then integer operation is performed, `a / b` is equal to the math operation `a/b` with fraction part removed.

```
1 / 2   -> 0.5  ->  0
3 / 2   -> 1.5  ->  1
-3 / 2  -> -1.5 -> -1
-3 / -2 -> 1.5  -> 1
```

As a matter of fact, `(a / b) * b + (a % b)` is always equal to `a`.

To perform a float number division, one of `a` and `b` need to be a float number, you can use both implicit and explicit conversion. Like `a * 1. / b` or `(double)a / b`

You can check [java 8 specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) for [multiplicative operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17) and [type conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

> The type of a multiplicative expression is the promoted type of its operands.
>   If the promoted type is int or long, then integer arithmetic is performed.
>   If the promoted type is float or double, then floating-point arithmetic is performed.
>   [15.17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17)

Comment: I already declared y as a double. SO shouldn't that work?

Comment: @OrchoSiddiqui No, it's not enough.

Comment: It's not enough because your `count` is Integer

Comment: @Orcho Siddiqui Your calculation side should have a float/double value, otherwise the end output will also be given in integer format.

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing ints together, which always produce an int. You should use doubles in order to get your result:

```
for(double count = 1; count <= n; count++){
    y += (count / ((2 * count) - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to what T & delta have mentioned you could try explicit type casting in the division so that the division actually returns a value of type correctness.

References:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Thanks,

-Abe.